# Вернуть данные из дочернего JFrame Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Подскажите пожалуйста. Я открываю в JFrame другой JFrame - дочерний. как мне можно получить данные из дочернего окна в родительский, по нажатию на ok?
Я знаю что есть JOptionPane но она мне не совсем подходит - там нельзя разместить много элементов

Comment: А можно как то конкретизировать вопрос? может какой то упрощенный пример? Потому что данные можно передать очень много как, в зависимости от структуры проекта, тот же DTO класс, например...

Comment: @Tachkin У меня есть родительское окно. В нём есть таблица. Мне нужно добавить `row` в ней и для этого я сделал кнопку. Через эту кнопку я вызываю другой `JFrame`. Изначально я думал сделать `JOptionPane`, он там мало что сделать можно, а мне нужно внести данные для каждого столбца в таблице, а там подгрузка данных с `json` и т.д. Пришлось делать отдельным `JFrame`. После того как мы выбрали данные в дочернем фрейме, мы нажимаем на `OK` и выбранные данные вносятся в таблицу.

Comment: как самое простое, действительно, как в ответе ниже, сохранять в объекте дочернего окна ссылку на родительский объект окна и писать данные.

Answer (score 2):

Можно так...

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Father();
    }
}

class Father extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JLabel label;

    public Father() {
        super("Я - родительское окно.");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        label = new JLabel("Пусто");
        getContentPane().add(label);

        setBounds(50, 50, 300, 100);
        setVisible(true);

        new Son(this);
    }

    protected void setLabel(String text) {
        label.setText(text);
    }
}

class Son extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Son(final Father parent) {
        super("Я - \"дочернее\" окно.");

        setBounds(250, 150, 250, 100);
        setVisible(true);

        JButton btClick = new JButton("Кликни");
        getContentPane().add(btClick);

        btClick.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //по клику на родительском изменится текст метки
                parent.setLabel("Полно");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста. Я открываю JDialog в родителе. Могу ли я получить доступ к методу родителя в этом JDialog? Я указываю родителя для JDialog.

Спасибо.

Comment: Эм, ну так же...
class Son extends JFrame{
меняется на
class Son extends JDialog{
и в супере добавляем parent. Всё остальное аналогично.

Comment: Так и сделано, но доступа у меня нет.

Comment: Класс Father и класс Son находятся в одном пакете? Если нет, то измените на паблик protected в setLabel.
Да и чего гадать, код выложите.

Comment: да, в одном пакете. У меня в родителе много элементов. НО мне нужно получить доступ к методу. и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Правильным решением будет использовать паттерн MVC. Описываете модель у нее должна быть возможность изменятся.

В родительском окне модель отображается как вы опишете (например, таблица). Дочернее окно будет иметь свой контроллер и будет иметь ссылку на вашу модель. По нажатию на кнопку **OK** контроллер будет менять модель.

Подробнее о MVC можно почитать в этом ответе https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/615287/215007

Comment: По типу как приведено ниже?

Comment: нет. другой ответ не использует методику, что я описал.

Comment: Не могли б вы привести банальный пример?

Comment: @Tsyklop пример реализации MVC?

Comment: да, именно его.

Comment: добавил это в ответ